# How to execute javascript from html page

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, httpresponse

I am making a request and reading the HTML content. The problem is that 90% of the content is JavaScript. How can I make the request and not get the JavaScript?

You can see here that `CurrentHtml` (the contents of the response) has JavaScript that contains elements that I need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jwplayer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">         jwplayer.key = "5yP+phROWS+QiNQny92l2iTFqbmzhyI/mT+Zsw==";</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/kyop_mock.js"></script>
        <script id="kyop-header" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">         
            <img class="left" src="${verticalBar}" />
            <img class="logoCabecera" src="${logo}" />
            <div class= "clearAll"></div>
        </script>

        <script id="kyop-links" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            {{each(index, adContent) contentTop}}
                <span class="enlacesWrapper">
                    {{if document != null}}
                          <span><a target="_blank" href="${document.fileUrl}" title="${contentTittle}" ratittle="${ratittle}" rapage="${rapage}">${contentTittle}</a></span>
                   {{else}}
                        {{if link != null && link != ""}}
                           <span><a onclick="showModalWindow('#kyop-modal-${index}');" title="${contentTittle}" ratittle="${link.ratittle}" rapage="${link.rapage}">${contentTittle}</a></span>
                           <div id="kyop-modal-${index}" class="kyop-container-ventanaModal" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="ventanaModal">
                                    <div class="right">
                                        <img src="img/cerrarGrandeAzul.png" onclick="closeModalWindow('#kyop-modal-${index}')" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; padding-bottom: 6px;">
                                    </div>  
                                    <div>
                                        <iframe class="kyop-modal-iframe" src="${link.linkUrl}" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
                                    </div>                      
                                </div>
                                <div class="fondoTransparente"></div>
                            </div>
                        {{else}}
                            <span><a title="${contentTittle}" ratittle="${ratittle}" rapage="${rapage}">${contentTittle}</a></span>
                        {{/if}}
                   {{/if}}
                   {{if contentIcon != null && contentIcon != ""}}
                       <img src="${contentIcon}" />
                   {{/if}}
                   <div class="clearAll"></div>
                </span>
            {{/each}}
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cajacentral" class="kyop_cajacentral" >
            <div id="cabecera" >                    
            </div>

            <div id="pie">
                <div id="pie_derecha">                  
                </div>
                <div id="pie_izquierda">
                    <b>&copy; BBVA S.A.</b> 
                </div>
                <div class="clearAll"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get a Page Source you will get everything which is on the page, that's obvious.

There are 2 things you can do!

1. Remove Javascript from main page and put in a .Js file and reference it on your HTML, so you will finally receive a html with just single line
2. Remove Javascript tag from HTML after you receive response

Something like this

```
 node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't request a page without JS from a server separately. because it's a file that the server send to clients. unless there is a web service that make it to you.
but you can parse the HTML file and clear JS tags easily.

[a wonderful parser](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery)